# Does Postgres provide an XA compliant resource manager?

Tags: postgresql, xa, microfocus, tuxedo

I would like to know if it is possible to use Postgres as a database backend with transaction monitors like Oracle Tuxedo or Microfocus Enterprise server on Linux.

This can be possible if postgres provides an XA compilant ressource manager...

I have searched on postgres website but couldn't find any relevant information about such support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Postgres supports 2PC via [prepared transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html), and the [JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/faq.html#xa) claims to be XA compliant (or near enough).

Answer (score 2):

psqlODBC provides an XA resource manager.

Comment: Thanks Craig. In the documentation, I see XA mentionned only in Windows context... Do you confirm it is supported also on Linux version of the driver?

Comment: Yes, it's there, `pgxalib`

Comment: Does anyone have an example to make Postgres work as Resource manager with Tuxedo as Transaction manager .  I am trying on Linux , using C++ applications.

Answer (score 0):

Enduro/X Middleware (almost clone to Tuxedo) ships with PostgreSQL XA driver for libpq and ecpg apis. Sample usage can be seen under https://github.com/endurox-dev/endurox/tree/master/atmitest/test067_postgres